# how to split fields after reading the file in R

Tags: r

I have a file with this format in each line:

```
f1,f2,f3,a1,a2,a3,...,an
```

Here, `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` are the fixed fields separated by `,`, but `f4` is the whole `a1,a2,...,an` where `n` can vary.

How can I read this into `R` and conveniently store those variable-length `a1` to `an`?

Thank you.

My file looks like the following

```
3,a,-4,news,finance
2,b,1,politics
1,a,0
2,c,2,book,movie
...
```

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but including a few typical lines in your question would help enormously.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, I added according to your request. Thank you.

Comment: Is your data exactly like the file you posted, or is the "f4" column quoted (as in `"news,finance"` or `"book,movie"`)? This would make a difference in the types of answers you receive.

Comment: Ananda Mahto: it is exactly as I posted. There is no quotes.

Comment: @QiangLi, how are you currently reading the data in, and what does the output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#
# Read example data
#
txt <- "3,a,-4,news,finance\n2,b,1,politics\n1,a,0\n2,c,2,book,movie"
tc = textConnection(txt)
lines <- readLines(tc)
close(tc)
#
# Solution
#
lines_split <- strsplit(lines, split=",", fixed=TRUE)
ind <- 1:3
df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(lines_split, "[", ind)))
df$V4 <- lapply(lines_split, "[", -ind) 
#
# Output
#
      V1 V2 V3            V4
1  3  a -4 news, finance
2  2  b  1      politics
3  1  a  0              
4  2  c  2   book, movie
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you mean by "conveniently store". If you think a data frame will suit you, try this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "3,a,-4,news,finance
2,b,1,politics
1,a,0
2,c,2,book,movie",
sep = ",", na.strings = "", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) 

names(df) <- c(paste0("f", 1:3), paste0("a", 1:(ncol(df) - 3)))
```

**Edit following @Ananda Mahto's comment.**
From `?read.table`:
"The number of data columns is determined by looking at the first five lines of input".
Thus, if the maximum number of columns with data occurs somewhere after the first five lines, the solution above will fail.

**Example of failure**

```
# create a file with max five columns in the first five lines,
# and six columns in the sixth row
cat("3, a, -4, news, finance",
"2, b, 1, politics",
"1, a, 0",
"2, c, 2, book,movie",
"1, a, 0",
"2, c, 2, book, movie, news",
file = "df",
sep = "\n")


# based on the first five rows, read.table determines that number of columns is five,
# and creates an incorrect data frame
df <- read.table(file = "df",
             sep = ",", na.strings = "", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
df
```

**Solution**

```
# This can be solved by first counting the maximum number of columns in the text file
ncol <- max(count.fields("df", sep = ","))

# then this count is used in the col.names argument
# to handle the unknown maximum number of columns after row 5.
df <- read.table(file = "df",
       sep = ",", na.strings = "", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE,
       col.names = paste0("f", seq_len(ncol)))

df

# change column names as above
names(df) <- c(paste0("f", 1:3), paste0("a", 1:(ncol(df) - 3))) 
df
```

Comment: If this is what they are looking for, you may need a `count.filelds` in there to help. `read.table` determines the number of columns from the first 5 lines of data; if the sixth line has more than either of the first 5, then the results are not at all what you would expect.

Comment: Good point @Ananda Mahto - thanks! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A place to start:

```
dat <- readLines(file) ## file being your file
df <- data.frame(
  f1=sapply(dat_split, "[[", 1),
  f2=sapply(dat_split, "[[", 2),
  f3=sapply(dat_split, "[[", 3),
  a=unlist( sapply(dat_split, function(x) {
    if (length(x) <= 3) { 
      return(NA)
    } else {
      return(paste(x[4:length(x)], collapse=","))
    }
  }) )
)
```

and when you need to pull things out of `a`, you can do splitting as necessary.